# android inflateexception masking memory error

Tags: android, out-of-memory, layout-inflater, inflate-exception

Some of my user crash reports are inflate exceptions, these are mainly due to memory errors that some devices get. Only about 0.2% of users get these for this particular app, but the devices themselves are not exactly low-end fringe devices.

How can I really prevent this, all my tests do not show memory leaks or anything, yet some of my users get this issue anyway.

Thoughts?

Comment: How much memory des your app consume?

Comment: @AlexS  I've seen logcat grow the heap to 22,000k before, but how exactly would I get this information?

Comment: I was thinking of the heapsize displayed in Android debug Monitor. What devices are affected? Are there devices that are (probably) not affected? The available heapsize differs depending on device.

Comment: How are you testing memory leaks?